# MbDotNet Mountebank .Net client throws No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, xunit, mountebank

[image]

[image]

Trying to use the [Mountebank .Net Client](https://github.com/mattherman/MbDotNet) for the test project

```
  _mbClient = new MountebankClient();
  _mbClient.DeleteAllImposters();
```

> HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target
>   machine actively refused it

Comment: Does it work sometimes? Normally this error means that the server exists but there is no endpoint listening. Is mountebank running behind a firewall?

Comment: hi @tomredfern I have figured it out. I will post an answer to this. Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that the MbDotNet doesn't have Mountebank integrated which makes sense.

I thought that I only need to install this Nuget package and it includes everything.

So the answer is: I need to go to the Mountbank website and install it, after that run

```
mb
```

to start the server, then run my Xunit .Net Core code, then the magic will happen.

If you would like a different url to host the MB server, then use its command line command to run it against different port and remember to pass in the new port number into your
**MountebankClient** constructor.

That's it :)